# What could cause a D7000's mirror to flap and "Err" to be displayed when trying to take a picture?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, shutter

When I press the shutter on my Nikon D7000, the mirror noisily flaps up and down — nothing else happens except 
`Err`  in display. It's not possible to take a picture and the
Aperture and Shutter wheels are not operating.

What caused this? I sold the camera and it was brought back next day in this sad state!

Comment: Did you sell the camera online or in person? Did the buyer inspect it at that time? What were your terms of sale?

Comment: You may or may not find the info here helpful: [Nikon D90 mirror stuck](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/74780/15871)

Comment: Reply to mattdm- person called to my house - I took sample shots with camera and 50mm lens while he was there. He did not know how to line up white dots to put the lens on. He already brought back a 10-20 lens which he had damaged!

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a power issue.  If the battery supplies inadequate voltage to the camera, the camera may fail to do all tasks necessary to take a photo - and opening the shutter is one of the more power-intensive tasks.

If the battery was not already fully charged, charge it and try again.  If that fails, buy a new battery for it, charge it fully, and try it again.  If you are lucky, a camera store nearby may have a battery that fits that you can use for testing.  (If so, buy your battery there, if your test is successful, as thanks to the store for letting you experiment.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a error on the display, look up the error in the user manual.  If you need more information, contact Nikon customer support.

Depending on the error, it might be something you can fix yourself (bad memory card, low battery voltage), or it might require professional repair service.

Again, start with the user's manual.