# Unable to click pictures with nikon D3500

Tags: nikon, digital, camera-settings, camera-basics, nikon-d3300

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1s_xLLeXyCNRJmyem2vkqLd-g9XnU3DZm?usp=sharing
here is the link of pictures and videos to my problems.

To describe it in words, my camera nikon d3500 is going half way click to autofocus but on full click is not taking any picture. Sometimes it shows error that Error. Press shutter release again. Even if this error is not displayed but still my camera is unable to take pictures.

I tried resetting the options but retouch menu is all greyed out, the reset menu in shooting menu is also greyed out. I also tried formatting the memory card and take the battery out for about 8 hours and re-insert it into the camera to reset the settings, but that did not work.

Comment: Could be a malfunctioning shutter, or mirror mechanism. Can you use LiveView mode on the camera?

Comment: In the video you link to, you are trying to capture images when the camera is only a few inches away from your computer's screen. The camera cannot focus that closely. Are you able to reliably take images when the camera can achieve focus on the subject (that is, when the subject is at least a couple feet away from the camera)?

Comment: @xenoid no I am unable to turn on the live mode, it says can not turn on the live mode please wait. and many other options in the setting shows this option is not available in current setting or current mode of the camera. I tried changing all the settings and modes of the camera but none helped

Comment: @scottbb I tried taking photos of distant objects, bright object, closer object, dark object  and still not able to capture photo

Comment: *"I am unable to turn on the live mode"* Sort of confirms that something is broken in the mirror or the shutter, because LV require the sensor to be exposed (mirror up and shutter open).

Comment: Thank you very much @xenoid for conforming that.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/74792/15871) to [Nikon D90 mirror stuck](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/74780/15871). The D3x00 series are the "descendants" of the D40, D50, and D60.

Comment: @MichaelC Thank you for your time but none of the solution helped me and finally had to replace the camera.