# remove the rewind button

Tags: repair

I am trying to repair my old analog camera. I have mirror that occasionally locks up, which can apparently be fixed with a drop of oil. For this I have to remove the bottom plate. Apart from a few simple screws, it is held back by the rewind button (shown in picture). It seems like it's easily removed by jamming two pins in the holes and twisting left, but I'm not gonna risk forcing it in case I'm wrong. What's the proper way to remove this?
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: what camera is this?

Comment: The proper way is carefully and cautiously. A camera is a complex precision mechanism full of bespoke components. Often the components are under spring tension or compression. You may need to make tools to have a chance of success. Every model of camera is different. Sometimes the same model is different too.

Comment: One can usually oil mirror box components via the hole on the front of the camera when the lens is removed. A toothpick or straightened paper clip to hold a drop of oil will allow one to place that drop on the pivot shaft that needs the lubrication, often just on the other side of the hole where the shaft passes through the side of the light box. For a similar example, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/74792/15871) to [Nikon D90 mirror stuck](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/74780/15871)

Comment: @Kahovius My best guess is a mamiya prismat cp. The model is not listed anywhere on the device, but I can't distinguish it from the pictures.

Comment: Exploded parts diagrams come in handy for preventing unintended consequences and collateral damage when taking things apart and one can't see what's on the other end of a fastener, or what is inside a cover before removing it..

Comment: It looks like a 2-pin anti-tamper screw. You can buy a box of variously sized hex-bits for a few $£€ on eBay Amazon etc. It's going to be too small for such as a watch-back wrench. & do note Ben's comment - things behind anti-tamper screws have a tendency to jump out & surprise you; that's often the reason they're behind anti-tamper screws in the first place ;) One last thing if you're doing this without a diagram - you don't know whether it's even going to be a right-handed thread, so don't force it too hard, try both directions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lens spanner wrench. It may be difficult to find one that accommodates such a small diameter, though. Personally I'd try the two pins method you suggest first – not much force should be needed, so probability of damage is low if you're careful. Maybe you could fashion a tool out of a paperclip? Another trick that sometimes works with similar buttons is to apply friction as you turn, using for example a piece of rubber between the button and your thumb.

(Are you sure though that the bottom plate is held back by this button and not by the battery cover?)

Answer (score 1):

Use a pair of point tipped metal tweezers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is removed by a caliper.  It will disfigure very easily so don't guess at it.   If memory serves it unscrews clockwise, but you haven't given the camera model so don't hold me to that.  BTW, you shouldn't 'oil' a sticking mirror.  You will just add to the problem.   Clean the lever's movements with lighter fluid or electronics cleaner and cotton swabs but don't overdo it.  Excess fluid will run onto the shutter. It's not a lack of oil that makes it stick.  It's a build up of old grease and gunk that causes the problem.